# EF4 ObjectStateManager not reporting changes?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, self-tracking-entities, objectstatemanager

I'm trying to implement a change auditing system at the context level using EF4 (database first). I'm overriding `SaveChanges` and capturing entities that have a state of `Added`, `Deleted`, or `Modified` from the context's `ObjectStateManager`. This normally works, but I've encountered an issue where none of the entities have this state (including entities that I have changed in code), but the context *does* have changes to the database. I've gone so far as to look at the list of entries with `Unchanged` as the state, and my modified entity is in that list.

The only complication that I can see is that I'm using self-tracking entities (as this is a WCF service that ordinarily sends these STE's down to the client for changes, then the client passes the modified STE's back up to persist the changes). **What seems to be happening is that objects that are retrieved on the server and modified directly there (rather than being passed to the client and using the STE's `ObjectChangeTracker`) are not being marked as `Modified`**. Is this normal/expected behavior? If this is the case, then clearly the context is using something *other* than the `ObjectStateManager` to determine what changes to persist to the database, as the changes *are* being made.

How can I detect these changes and keep track of them? Does anyone know what it is that the context is using to track changes? I had always assumed it was the `ObjectStateManager`, but that seems not to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue is with the `saveOptions`. Since these options (by default) include `DetectChangesBeforeSave`, the context was calling `DetectChanges` internally, which picked up the modifications and properly set the state of the `ObjectStateEntry`. By adding this to my audit routine:

```
if ((options & SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave) == 
               SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave)
{
    DetectChanges();

    options ^= SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave;
}
```

It now works correctly.